# Apply chain rule to $u = y^{1 - n}$ in order to find $\frac{du}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $u = y^{1 - n}$.

I know that, by using the chain rule:

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Also, I know that $\frac{du}{dy} = (1 - n)y^{-n} = \frac{1 - n}{y^{n}}$

Now, for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, I must re-arrange $u = y^{1 - n}$ to make $u = \frac{y}{n}$, where $nu = y$.

Hence, given that u, and n, are constant:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}[un] = 0 $$

$$ \frac{du}{dx} = 0 \cdot \frac{1 - n}{y^{-n}} = 0$$

Comment: Does y depend on x ? If it is the case, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$. If not, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.

Comment: If you does not know the function $y(x)$ you can not find $y'$. Iour rearrengemet is wrong: from $u=y^{1-n}$ you can not find $u=\frac{y}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making some inappropriate leaps. For one thing, I don't know how you went about your "rearrangement" of $u=y^{1-n},$ but you should have $$u=\frac{y}{y^n}\neq\frac{y}{n}.$$

Secondly, $u$ is explicitly a *nonconstant* function of $y$, and $y$ is *implied* to be a function of $x.$ The *only* way that $u$ can be constant is if $y$ is a constant function, which *we must not assume*.

Finally, unless you know *how* $y$ depends on $x,$ you cannot give a specific expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}.$ Hence, the best answer you're going to get (unless you have more context that you haven't told us about) is $$\frac{1-n}{y^n}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}.\tag{$\star$}$$

This may seem distressing, but it might help to think of $u$ as the *form* that some function of $x$ might take, so our derivative of $u$ (with respect to $x$) should be just as formal. If we happen to know how $y$ depends on $x$ *precisely*, then the form $(\star)$ allows us to quickly calculate said derivative precisely. For example, if $u=(\ln x)^{1-n}$--that is, if $y=\ln x$--then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1x,$ and so by $(\star),$ $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1-n}{(\ln x)^n\cdot x}.$$ Or if $u=(\sin x)^{1-n}$--that is, if $y=\sin x$--then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos x,$ and so by $(\star),$ $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{(1-n)\cos x}{(\sin x)^n}.$$

Comment: Hey thanks for the great reply!!! Yes i realised the question was broken it was actually part of a bigger question. I actually had to get end up with $\frac{dy}{dx} = (1-n)Y^{-n} \times \frac{dy}{dx} $

Where $\frac{dy}{dx} = q(x)y^{n} - p(x)y$ as re-arranged from a given equation